Can git-daemon disallow shallow fetches?
I'm operating a public mirror site where the git daemon is occasionally hogging memory and CPU. I've traced down to some AOSP repos where object pack files can go as large as 50 GB each.
The systemd service for our git daemon is like this:
[Service]
Type=simple
Nice=19
#IOSchedulingClass=idle
IOSchedulingClass=best-effort
IOSchedulingPriority=6
IOAccounting=true
#CPUAffinity=00000000110000000000000000000000
ExecStart=/usr/lib/git-core/git-daemon --user=gitdaemon --reuseaddr --verbose --export-all --forbid-override=receive-pack --timeout=180 --max-connections=32 --base-path=/srv/git

MemoryMax=32G
MemoryHigh=28G

In addition to the cgroup settings (memory.max and memory.high as shown above), I would also like to prevent clients from doing shallow clones / fetches from our server for certain repos.
I've looked through git documentation and only found client settings (e.g. clone.rejectShallow). Is there something I can do on the server side to reject shallow upload-pack access?

Why do you think the problem is in shallow clones? IMO shallow clones should produce smaller packs.
